# CS8602 – Possible null reference – How to resolve properly this warning?

Tags: c#, linq

Resharper gives a possible null reference warning . Is there any possibility how to resolve warning not to using '!' mark?

[image: Solved warning this ! mark]

I know what '!' says to Visual studio what ignore this warning but how to solve it in proper way?
method what rises this warning

```
 public IQueryable<AddressListData> GetAllForAddressList(int userId)
        {
            return dataContext.Addresses
                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                .Include(u => u.Country)
                .Include(u => u.User)
                .Select(u => new AddressListData
                {
                    Id = u.Id,
                    StreetAddress = u.StreetAddress,
                    City = u.City,
                    FullName =  u.User.FullName, //this rises warning
                    CountryName = u.Country!.Name //bad solution of warning
                });
        }
```

```
public class AddressListData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string City { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string CountryName { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    }
```

```
public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string Zip { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        public  User? User { get; set; } 
        public  Country? Country { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if `u.User` is null? (It's a nullable property, after all.) If `u.User` can't be null, explain why. Then we can find out if this is an explanation that the compiler will accept as well.

Comment: Why is it a bad solution? Seems perfectly fine to use `!` to me. You're working with a queryable that's translated into a database query and not C# code that can cause a null reference error.

Comment: @Heinzi User could not be null because you cannot create address without user in my create form.  In my website any logged user can create addresses and you cannot create address without user .

Comment: Then `Address.User` should not be nullable.

Comment: @PMF then it rises another warning now in Address model. Warning- non nullable property 'User' must contain non-null value then exiting constructor. Consider declaring it nullable

Comment: `then it rises another warning now in Address model` Yes, which should inform you that it's not true to say `you cannot create address without user` because clearly you can, just by doing `var address = new Address()`;

Comment: To resolve that one, add a constructor to `Address` and initialize it's User property there.

Comment: Here's how I've handled nullable references with EF navigation properties.  If I know that I always include the property when doing queries then I define it like this `public  User User { get; set; } = null!;`,  If there's ever a time when you would query `Address` and not include `User` then you should leave it nullable and just use the null forgiveness operator in the queries.  Long story short is that for EF and nullable references there's no way around not using the null forgiveness operator.

Comment: @PMF That would not fix the problem because the EF requires a parameterless constructor on the Entity.

Comment: @juharr It requires a parameterless constructor, yes. But you can still fill in this constructor with something like initializing string properties to `String.Empty` instead of null.

Comment: @PMF It's not a `string` property.  It's a Navigation property and you should not be initializing it at all, you want EF to either leave it null or let it set it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with FullName and CountryName potentially being null as well then one solution is the "[Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)"

As you say u.Country!.Name is using a null forgiving operator, essentially ignoring the issue.
If you use the null conditional, if the left hand object is null, instead of the property accessor causing an error, instead it completes the initial assignment as null as well.
This can also be chained to further properties.

Example:

```
CountryName = u.Country?.Name
AnotherValue = u.Address?.City?.SomethingElse
```

Comment: You cannon use the null conditional operator in EF queries.

Answer (score -1):

I found solution, is to check if actual model is null if so place it as null if not then call further query/ This is done by ternary if statement

more understandable in code

```
public IQueryable<AddressListData> GetAllForAddressList(int userId)
        {
            return dataContext.Addresses
                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                .Include(u => u.Country)
                .Include(u => u.User)
                .Select(u => new AddressListData
                {
                    Id = u.Id,
                    StreetAddress = u.StreetAddress,
                    City = u.City,
                    FullName =  u.User.FullName, //this rises warning
                    CountryName = u.Country!.Name //bad solution of warning
                });
        }
```

```
public IQueryable<AddressListData> GetAllForAddressList(int userId)
        {
            return dataContext.Addresses
                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                .Include(u => u.Country)
                .Include(u => u.User)
                .Select(u => new AddressListData
                {
                    Id = u.Id,
                    StreetAddress = u.StreetAddress,
                    City = u.City,
                    FullName = u.User != null ? u.User.FullName : string.Empty,//here is solution
                    CountryName = u.Country != null ? u.Country.Name : string.Empty,//it checks if model is null if so places null 
                });
        }
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `u.User?.FullName ?? string.Empty`.

Comment: As Heinzi mentioned, if you use the null conditional in my answer with null coalescing you can simplify more.

Comment: Don't do this. If user shall not be null, then make sure it is not. This is just a workaround and not much better than using the !.

Comment: yeah, think about it, why User could be null ? That warning message you got is just trying to tell you to fix this at the source of the problem.

Comment: @Heinzi You cannot use the null conditional operator `?` in an EF query.